# Manually run JQuery Unobtrusive Validation with Knockout Templates

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, unobtrusive-validation

I am passing a asp.net mvc model down to knockout that has all the data annotations on it that I would like to validate against.

The premise is that I have multiple knockout templates that get swapped out showing only the model properties that I care about at any given time. The multiple templates create a flow as if you were stepping through a wizard and filling out the relevant properties on each step.

The template that is loaded is wrapped in a `<form></form>` tag in order to use the unobtrusive validation.  I have it wired on the knockout's template binding "afterRender" to run the validation on the current loaded template.

It is at this point that I am trying to figure out how to validate the current state of the form and have ran into nothing but issues with the form always being "valid".

According to this [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/03/05/unobtrusive-client-side-validation-with-dynamic-contents-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) I should be able to call:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(jquery object)
```

then be able to call:

```
$('form').valid()
```

I have also tried acquiring the validator for the specific node `$(selector).validate()` and calling valid().

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem, but it seemed the problem lies within `jquery.validation.unobtrusive.js`. Try to use only `jquery.validation.js` and see if it worked.